# Find the general solution of the simple harmonic oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Question: Find the general solution of the simple harmonic oscillator equation,
$$\ddot{x}=-\omega^2x$$

My answer: $x(t)=A\cos(\omega t)+B\sin(\omega t)$

Solution given: $x(t)=x_0\cos(\omega t)+\frac{\dot{x_0}}{\omega}\sin(\omega t)$

I can understand inputting $x_0$ for $A$, but can't understand inputting $\frac{\dot{x_0}}{\omega}$ for $B$. Where does the input for $B$ come from?

Comment: From boundary conditions; the first is $x(0)=x_0$; the second one defines $x'(0)=$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input of $B$ is given by the initial value of the velocity. Since your ODE is of second order, you need to give conditions on the velocity, too. Hence, The condition $$\dot{x}(0)=\dot{x_0}$$ leads to $B=\frac{\dot{x_0}}{\omega}$.

Comment: how does this lead to specifically $\frac{\dot{x_0}}{\omega}$?

Comment: You just have to differentiate your general solution and impose that the condition is satisfied. The general solution is of the form $$x(t)=Acos(\omega t)+Bsin(\omega t),$$ hence $$\dot{x}(t)=-\omega Asin(\omega t)+\omega Bcos(\omega t),$$ which at $t=0$ becomes $$\dot{x}(0)=\omega B.$$

Comment: Great answer thanks